# How to count all alphabetical characters in array?

Tags: java, counter, nested-loops

So basically my objective is to make a program that takes the user input and reverses it and prints the inverse character back to user as an encoded message. Right now i need to print the statistics of the user entered string.
How do i count the amount of occurrences of different letters from the user string. I have this so far.

```
   import java.util.*;

  public class SecretCodeMachine
 {
  public static void main(String[]args)
 {
    //object accessing the non static methods
    SecretCodeMachine a = new SecretCodeMachine();

    //input stream
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner i = new Scanner (System.in);

    //prompt the user
    System.out.println("Please input your secret message.");
    String input = in.nextLine();

    //calls the encodedMessage() method; equals the return value to varaible
    String encodedMessage = a.encodeMessage(input);

    //message and prompt
    System.out.println("Encoded message: " + encodedMessage);
    System.out.println("Enter the code in here to get the original message back.");
    String input2 = i.nextLine();

    //if statements saying that if the input equals the encoed message...
    if (input2.equals(encodedMessage))
    {
        //print this
        System.out.println("Original Message: " + input);
    }
    else
    {
        //prints when doesnt equal
        System.out.println("Message not found.");
    }

    //closes the input stream
    i.close();
    in.close();

}
//method for encoding the string from array
public String encodeMessage(String pass)
{
    //passes the parameter string and puts it in an array ()
    char[] toArray = pass.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < toArray.length; i++) 
    {
        //does the lower case characters
        if (toArray[i] >= 'a' && toArray[i] <= 'z') 
        {
            if (toArray[i] - 'a' <= 13) toArray[i] = (char) ('z' - (toArray[i] - 'a'));
            else toArray[i] = (char) ('a' + ('z' - toArray[i]));
        }

        //does the upper case characters
        else if(toArray[i] >= 'A' && toArray[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            if (toArray[i] - 'A' <= 13) toArray[i] = (char) ('Z' - (toArray[i] - 'A'));
            else toArray[i] = (char) ('A' + ('Z' - toArray[i]));
        }
        //if the characters are non alphatbetic 
        else 
        {
            toArray[i] = toArray[i];
        }
    }

    //converts the toArray back to new string 
    String encodedMessage = new String(toArray);

    //returns the encodedMessage string
    return encodedMessage;
}
```

}

So how would i keep a track off all the letters that are entered by the user?

Comment: Here is a strategy: 1) Put all the characters the user entered in a `Set`. 2) Maintain a `Map` of each of the characters in the `Set` and its frequency (which you are about to find out) initialized to zero. 3) Iterate through each character in the user input string, and increment the frequency of character in the `Map` if it is found in the `Set`.

Comment: You could use a hashmap <key, value> example <a, 2> <b, 4>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class SecretCodeMachine
 {
     HashMap<Character, Integer> charCounts = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();//add hashmap here
```

Code for updating count for each character:

```
for (int i = 0; i < toArray.length; i++) 
    {
        //does the lower case characters
```

---

```
        //update count for character
        if(charCounts.get(toArray[i]) != null)
        {
            charCounts.put(toArray[i], (charCounts.get(toArray[i]) + 1));
        }
        else
        {
            charCounts.put(toArray[i], 1);
        }
```

---

```
        if (toArray[i] >= 'a' && toArray[i] <= 'z') 
        {
            if (toArray[i] - 'a' <= 13) toArray[i] = (char) ('z' - (toArray[i] - 'a'));
            else toArray[i] = (char) ('a' + ('z' - toArray[i]));
        }

        //does the upper case characters
        else if(toArray[i] >= 'A' && toArray[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            if (toArray[i] - 'A' <= 13) toArray[i] = (char) ('Z' - (toArray[i] - 'A'));
            else toArray[i] = (char) ('A' + ('Z' - toArray[i]));
        }
        //if the characters are non alphatbetic 
        else 
        {
            toArray[i] = toArray[i];
        }
    }
```

You could use a hashmap to store characters and integers.  Key/Value pair only one entry for each key per map.  Example

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a map with key as character and count as integer. Below is the method which could help you:

```
public Map<Character, Integer> getCharCount(String input) {
  Map<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
  Integer count;
  for (int i =0; i<input.length();i++) {
    count = charCountMap.get(input.charAt(i));
    if (count == null) {
      charCountMap.put(input.charAt(i), 1);
    } else {
      charCountMap.put(input.charAt(i), count + 1);
    } 
  }
  return charCountMap;
}
```